# getting arduino PWM from 0-5V to 0-10V or 0-12V?

Tags: arduino, mosfet, switches, dc-dc-converter, mosfet-driver

I have an IR2110 driver and a LOD voltage regulator 15V from a solar panel. now this will supply 15V to VCC as shown below. Since I have a LOD voltage regulator of 15V, I can't apply the same voltage to VDD and Vin (arduino). Therefore, I bought a 12V regulator that will be applied to VCC and VD as long as PWM signals from the arduino be 0-12V. Is there a solution that make pwm go up to 0-12V?
note also I have one PWM and its inverse coming out of the arduino.

1)Is there a solution that make pwm go up to 0-12V?

2) What effects on the driver if I reduce VCC to 12V?

3) Is there formula for capacitors other than the bootstrap one and what their purpose?

I know it is a lot of questions, but if I get any help, I really appreciated :)

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Is there a solution that make pwm go up to 0-12V?

   Yes, you can use level shifters in this case
2. What effects on the driver if I reduce VCC to 12V?

   What I get from data sheet is it will increase the Turn OFF Delay, Turn ON Delay, Shutdown Time.
3. Is there formula for capacitors other than the bootstrap one and what their purpose?

   What do you mean by this?